# RVIZ Transform error Base_link and Camera_link

Tags: ros

I am working on a differential drive robot with two motor wheels with encoders and caster wheels. The robot also has an Intel RealSense depth camera.

When I launch RVIZ: The Global option > Fixed frame is set to `Base_link` and shows all the transforms for the differential driver nodes. But an error appears for the Depth camera nodes with message saying:

```
No transform from Camera_depth_frame to baselink
No transform from Camera_depth_optical_frame to baselink
No transform from Camera_link to baselink
No transform from Camera_rgb_frame to baselink
```

If I change the Global option > fixed frame to `Camera_link`, I can see all the transforms for the depth camera but now the differential drive transforms are not available

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell ROS the relationship between the camera frame the robot base. If you have a URDF model of your robot, add the Camera_link to the model and link it to the base.

If you don't have a URDF model, I think you can broadcast the transform yourself. See [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20(C%2B%2B)).

Comment: I agree with 'hammer'. If you already have a URDF file for your robot you can just add a description to it that defines the relative location of the existing links and joints. Follow this example that uses a Kinect. http://answers.ros.org/question/9138/how-to-add-kinect-sensor-input-to-a-urdf-model/ Good luck.